# Can I build a resultset from a file in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc, csv, text-files, resultset

I don't have much experience working with resultsets, but as ResultSet is an interface, I guess I could implement it to work with a file as a backend. Is this nonsense? Is there any solution already given for my problem?

Comment: Have you looked for existing text-to-resultset adapters?

Comment: Interesting question..  why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Marcus: Sometimes the datasource is a large generated file and sometimes it's a table, and the code needs to be flexible enough to handle both. Usually this scenario happens in testing (rarely in the final product). You may want that sort of detail hidden from the code that actually processes the data, so all it cares about is a ResultSet... or at least that's how I've seen it happen before. He may have different reasons ;)

Comment: It's actually a performance test. I have to do some queries that are really slow when done on a db, but fast when done by a script on a text file. It sounds crazy, but I want to be sure before discarding the text file option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like there already is a [Csv2JDBC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csvjdbc/) project, that may contain at least an example implementation of ResultSet.

Answer (score 2):

[HSQL](http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFeatures.html) also provides support for interpreting csv files as `ResultSet`s.